# Parameters in Report Viewer control in Mozilla are disabled

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, mozilla

I am desperate.

I have web app that can call reports from report server. On one report, there is six parameters, where the last two are datetime parameter. Some parameters are dependable of other, but datetimes are not.

When I start this app on my machine, everything is good.

On client side, there are 4 machines, where one is separate from other three. on that separate machine is everything OK also, but on other three I have strange problem.

By the way, when I run report from reports list, I get report viewer control on which are six parameters. Some of them are filled automatically, let's say first three, fourth is multiple choice, and when I check one item in that list, then last two parameter need to be enabled. But even after choosing item in list, datetime parameters are disabled.

By the way, I was deployed same report with datetime parameters placed as first and second, and when run, they are enabled, but now is last two again disabled.

To things be worse, this is happening only for one user one all three machine, other users generate report normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you could try to clear browse history on problematic client machines. Then try access reports. It should help to solve your problem.